# Get class mapped information Hiberante JpaTransactionManager

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, sessionfactory

I'm trying to get programmatically to the data of a Hibernate mapped class.
I could've done like this:

```
sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(o.getClass());
```

But I'm using JpaTransactionManager so I don't have sessionFactory, as far as I know. Does anybody knows a solution?
Would it be a nightmare to change to HibernateTransactionManager and have sessionFactory to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
@Component
public class MetadataInfo {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    private ClassMetadata getClassMetadata() {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        ClassMetadata classMetadata = session.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(User.class);

        return classMetadata;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it in your DAO classes and where you already have a Session reference you can simply call:

```
session.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(o.getClass());
```

If you need it from the and you are using JPA 2.1 you can use:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = jpaTransactionManager.getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(o.getClass());
```

If you don't use JPA 2.1 you can then:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = jpaTransactionManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(o.getClass());
...
entityManager.close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vlad. It really helped me. I couldn't do it exactly as you do but I was able to get the entityManager and do almost the same.